# Luminance HDR - Canon CR2 - Black images

Tags: canon, raw, hdr, luminance

I've been using QTPFSGUI few years ago and I wanted to do some HDR images recently... on my mac...

So I downloaded today the last version 2.6.0 available and tried to create my HDR from 3 CR2 images (Canon raw).

The resulting hdr image is quite confusing to me because it is almost black / purple, it's like "raw decompression" isn't going well... any suggestions on how to update the raw decompression tool used by Luminance HDR ?

Thanks

3 CR2 input image with 1EV exposure difference
[image: 3 cr2 images before processing]

Manuel alignement + auto anti ghost
Histo seems good, but not the image actually, too dark already.
[image: manual alignement + anti ghost]

default hdr configuration parameters (profile 1)
[image: hdr configuration parameters]

The preview...
[image: the preview]

[image]